# cakephp form input and url params

Tags: forms, cakephp, parameters

I have a form that takes some input from a user and then gets redirected to a new page/function of the controller, I need to post.redirect.get the param so that I can use the `id` of the `invoice` on the next page.

here is the first controller(where information is added)

```
public function add(){
    $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Create Invoice');
    $this->set('stylesheet_used', 'homestyle');
    $this->set('image_used', 'eBOXLogoHome.png');   
    $this->layout='home_layout';

    if($this->request->is('post')){


        //$this->Invoice->create();
        if(($this->Invoice->set($this->request->data))){
            $this->Session->setFlash('The invoice has been saved');
            $data=$this->request->data;
            if($this->Invoice->saveAll($data,array('validate'=>false))){
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invoice Created'));
            $this->redirect(array(
            'controller' => 'invoices','action' => 'create',
            $this->data['invoices']['id']));
            }
    }}
    else
    {
        $this->Session->setFlash('The invoice could not be saved. Please, try again.');
    }

     $templates=$this->Template->find('list', array(
    'fields'=>array('name'),
    'conditions' => array(
    'account_id' => $this->Auth->user('account_id'))));

    $accounts2=$this->User->find('list', array(
    'fields'=>array('account_id'),
    'conditions' => array(
    'id' => $this->Auth->user('id'))));

    $sendername=$this->Account->find('list', array(
    'fields'=>array('company_name'),'conditions' => array(
    'id' => $accounts2)));

    $accounts=$this->User->Relationship->find('list', array(
    'fields'=>array('receiver_id'),
    'conditions' => array(
    'sender_id' => $accounts2)));

    $receivername=$this->Account->find('list', array(
    'fields'=>array('company_name'),'conditions'=>array(
    'id' => $accounts)));

    $this->set('accounts', $accounts);
    $this->set('accounts2', $accounts2);
    $this->set('sendername', $sendername);
    $this->set('receivername', $receivername);
    $this->set('template', $templates);


  }
```

here is the view

### Create a New Invoice

```
<?php


echo $this->Form->create('Invoice', array('action'=>'add'));


echo $this->Form->input('id',array('type'=>'hidden'));
echo $this->Form->input('sender_id', array('label' =>'Sender: ', 'type' => 'select', 'options' => $sendername));
echo $this->Form->input('receiver_id',array('label'=>'Receiver: ', 'type' => 'select', 'options' => $receivername));
echo $this->Form->input('active', array('label' => 'Schedule?', 'options' => array('1'=>'Send','0'=>'Schedule'), 'default'=>'1'));
echo $this->Form->input('templates_id', array('label'=>'Template: ','type'=>'select','options'=>$template));
echo $this->Form->end('Submit');


?>
```

and here is the controller that I want to pass the param too

```
public function create($id)
    {   
$fields = $this->Template->Field->find('all',array( 
          'conditions' => array(
          'template_id'=> $id,
         'Field.active'=>true)));
        if(empty($this->data)){
            $this->data= $this->Template->read(NULL, $id);
        } 
        else{
            if(($this->Template->save($this->data)))
            {
                $this->Session->setFlash('The template has been updated');
                $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'Templates', 'action'=>'view'));

            }
        }

     }
          $this->set('field', $fields);


    }
```

Comment: `$this->redirect( array('controller' => 'Invoices','action' => 'create', $this->data['invoices']['id']));` just change the controller you redirect to after adding the invoice? `Invoices` > `Template`

Comment: i do not understand? i want to stay in the invoices controller?

Comment: You said you want to pass the `id` to the `create` method of (presumably) the `Template` controller. After you successfully add an `invoice` in the invoice controller, redirect to `template/create/id`.

Comment: either way its not passing the params with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public function add(){
    $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Create Invoice');
    $this->set('stylesheet_used', 'homestyle');
    $this->set('image_used', 'eBOXLogoHome.png');   
    $this->layout='home_layout';

    if($this->request->is('post')){


        //$this->Invoice->create();
        if(($this->Invoice->set($this->request->data))){
            $this->Session->setFlash('The invoice has been saved');
            $data=$this->request->data;
            if($this->Invoice->saveAll($data,array('validate'=>false))){
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invoice Created'));
            debug($this->Invoice->id);
            $this->redirect(array(
            'controller' => 'invoices','action' => 'create', 
            'invoice' => $this->Invoice->id));
            }
    }}
    else
    { 
        $this->Session->setFlash('The invoice could not be saved. Please, try again.');
    }

     $templates=$this->Template->find('list', array(
    'fields'=>array('name'),
    'conditions' => array(
    'account_id' => $this->Auth->user('account_id'))));

    $accounts2=$this->User->find('list', array(
    'fields'=>array('account_id'),
    'conditions' => array(
    'id' => $this->Auth->user('id'))));

    $sendername=$this->Account->find('list', array(
    'fields'=>array('company_name'),'conditions' => array(
    'id' => $accounts2)));

    $accounts=$this->User->Relationship->find('list', array(
    'fields'=>array('receiver_id'),
    'conditions' => array(
    'sender_id' => $accounts2)));

    $receivername=$this->Account->find('list', array(
    'fields'=>array('company_name'),'conditions'=>array(
    'id' => $accounts)));

    $this->set('accounts', $accounts); 
    $this->set('accounts2', $accounts2); 
    $this->set('sendername', $sendername); 
    $this->set('receivername', $receivername);
    $this->set('template', $templates);


  }
```